# SQL Server : Query Union All Converting Type Failed

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to run a query to pull back data from two tables using a union all and keep getting the following:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 29
>   Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'ie9' to data type int.

I'm not sure why anything is trying to convert it should be able to show its table data??

Here is my SQL:

```
SELECT 
    CustomerNumber, Event
FROM 
    CustomerPortal.dbo.WebLog
WHERE 
    (Event = 'exception') 
    AND (CreateDate >= '04/03/2015') AND (CreateDate <= '04/06/2015')

UNION ALL

SELECT distinct 
    BrowserId, BrowserName 
FROM 
    CustomerPortal.dbo.BrowserInfoLog;
```

Comment: you are using a `UNION`, so columns should be from compatible data types, what data type is `CustomerNumber` and `BrowserID`?

Comment: Customer is int and BrowserID is nvarchar(128). I can't really change those types at this stage but I'm basically trying to show the exceptions and customer number along side the event type and browser name...

Comment: So, are you still not sure why is trying to convert it?, one is an `INT` and the other a `NVARCHAR`

Comment: I understand that, so my question now is... how can I display the data as well? Or is there a way.

Comment: yes, you need to convert your int to nvarchar first

Answer (score 0):

You can turn your CustomerNumber into nvarchar so it matches your BrowserID like this:

```
SELECT  CAST(CustomerNumber AS NVARCHAR(128)) AS CustomerNumber ,
        Event
FROM    CustomerPortal.dbo.WebLog
WHERE   ( Event = 'exception' )
        AND ( CreateDate >= '04/03/2015' )
        AND ( CreateDate <= '04/06/2015' )
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT
        BrowserId ,
        BrowserName
FROM    CustomerPortal.dbo.BrowserInfoLog;
```